# STM32F407VG Discovery + CMSIS HSE Clock Configuration

Tags: stm32, arm, clock-speed, cmsis

I am trying to program an STM32F4 discovery board using Vscode, Platformio and CMSIS. However, I cannot set the right clock frequency. I have programmed it to blink an LED every second, except it seems to be blinking every 3 seconds.

This is my desired clock configuration:

[image]

This is the code that I have configuring the clock:

```
// Enable the HSE in bypass mode (there is a 8MHz signal coming from the ST-LINK)
RCC->CR |= RCC_CR_HSEBYP | RCC_CR_HSEON;
while(!(RCC->CR & RCC_CR_HSERDY));

//Set the main PLL M, N, P, Q, R, and HSE as the input
//STM32F4DISCOVERY: M = 4, N = 168, P = 2 = 168Mhz SYSCLK, Q = 7, R = N/A (Q & R not used)
RCC->PLLCFGR = (4 << RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLM_Pos) | (168 << RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLN_Pos) | (2 << RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLP_Pos) | (7 << RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLQ_Pos) | RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLSRC_HSE;
RCC->CR |= RCC_CR_PLLON;

// set APB prescalers
// APB1 = 4, APB2 = 2
//STM32F4DISCOVERY: 42Mhz and 84Mhz
RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_PPRE1_DIV4 | RCC_CFGR_PPRE2_DIV2;

// wait for PLL lock
while(!(RCC->CR & RCC_CR_PLLRDY));

// Switch SYSCLK to PLL
RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_SW_PLL;

SystemCoreClockUpdate();
```

I have checked what the clock is actually set to by debugging using the onboard ST-Link and I am even more confused.

Before the clock is configured, `SystemCoreClock` is 16000000 (HSI frequency, makes sense)

After the clock is configured, `SystemCoreClock` is 175000000 (I have no idea where this number is coming from, and it is faster than the 168Mhz max, while the LED blinks 3 times slower)

Can someone tell me what is going on and how to fix it? Thank you.

For reference, here is the LED blink code:

```
// Call this after setting up the clock
void SysTick_Init(void) {
    // Enable the SysTick interrupt every 1ms
    SysTick_Config(SystemCoreClock / 1000);
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(SysTick_IRQn);
}

uint32_t millis(void) {
    return ticks;
}

void delay_ms(uint32_t t) {
  //uint32_t elapsed;
  uint32_t start = millis();
  do {
  //  elapsed = millis() - start;
  } while (millis() - start < t) ;
}

void SysTick_Handler(void) {
    ticks++;
}

int main(void) {
    initClock();
    SysTick_Init();

    RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIODEN;              // enable the clock to GPIO
    LEDPORT->_MODER |= GPIOMODER;   // set pins to be general purpose output
    for (;;) {
        delay_ms(1000);
        LEDPORT->ODR ^= (1<<LED1);  // toggle diodes
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Spend some time studying the provided standard peripheral examples and the library sources behind them to understand how they work, then transfer what you've learned to your problem.

Comment: where are the examples provided?

Comment: In the ST download for the board, takes all of five seconds to find with a web search including copies on github

Comment: This? https://github.com/k-code/stm32f4-examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the problem, two things were configured wrong.

1. Platformio by default has `#define HSE_VALUE    ((uint32_t)25000000)` in system_stm32f4xx.c. This is not the case with the discovery board, which has a 8Mhz crystal, not a 25Mhz one. I changed this to 8000000
2. In order to achieve divide by 2, PLLP actually has to be set to 0, not 2.